# How to create a loop with considering combination of columns in R

Tags: r, for-loop, subset

My data set looks like this:
[image: Data set]  My goal is creating many attributes by combining current variables. For example I want to create an attributes which called **HS_POC**, This attributes shows Yes when we have same application in our data set with application status are  H or S and postal code is exactly the same otherwise is NO. Code to do that is:

```
  sub <-subset(
    data,
    status  %in% c("H","S"),
    select = c(
     status,
      applications,
      postalcode))

attributes <-data.frame(setDT(sub)[, .(.N, applications) , by =
                          .(
                            status,
                            postalcode
                          )][N > 1])
attributes <- subset(attributes,
         select = c(applications, N))
attributes$N <- "Yes"
colnames(attributes)[colnames(attributes) == "N"] <- "HS_POC"
train <-
  merge(data, attributes, by = "applications", all.x =
          TRUE)
data$HS_POC <- data$HS_POC %>% replace_na("No")
```

and the result is a new column like this
[image: Result].

What I would like to do is creating many columns like **HS_POC** with combination of other variables for example **HS_date of birth**, **HS_product type**, **HS_first name** and... I create a loop for that but it is very slow, how can I improve that in terms of speed.

```
    library(data.table)
data<-read.csv("test.csv")
Indep.var<-subset(data, select=-c(applications,Status))
aa<- colnames(Indep.var)
table<- t(combn(aa,2))
table<-data.frame(table)
table$Status<-c("Status")
table_status<- table
table_status<- as.matrix(table_status)
table$applications<-c("applications")
table_final<- as.matrix(table)
table_final[1,]
##paste(table_final[1,1],table_final[1,2],sep = "_")
##nrow(table_final)
N<-nrow(table_final)
for (i in 1:N)
{
  sub <- subset(data,
                Status  %in% c("H", "S"),
                select = table_final[i, ])

  attributes <- data.frame(setDT(sub)[, .(.N, applications) , by =
                                        eval(table_status[i,])][N > 1])
  attributes <- subset(attributes,
                       select = c(applications, N))

  if (nrow(attributes)== 0){
    colnames(attributes)[colnames(attributes) == "N"] <- paste("HS", table_final[i, 1], table_final[i, 2], sep = "_")
    data <- merge(data, attributes, by = "applications", all.x =
                    TRUE)

  }else{

  attributes$N <- "Yes"
  colnames(attributes)[colnames(attributes) == "N"] <- paste("HS", table_final[i, 1], table_final[i, 2], sep = "_")
  data <- merge(data, attributes, by = "applications", all.x =
            TRUE)
}
}


library(tidyr)
data %>% replace_na("No")
data[is.na(data)] <- "No"
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Welcome to SO! `This attributes shows Yes when we have same application in our data set with application status are H or S and postal code is exactly the same` — exactly the same as what?

Comment: I have a feeling that this can be made significantly easier, but in the current form it is really hard to understand.